# using helpers properly in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It looks like you cannot use a helper in a controller even if both of them belong to the same class. For example: XYZHelper and XYZController...

I was under the impression that if the prefix is the same "XYZ" then the method in the helper can be used in the controller and in the view, but I think this is not the case.

So how do I remove some common functionality from a controller and place it in a helper. I want to place that piece of code in a helper because other controllers may be using it. What is the best way to approach this.

Thanks,
Jai.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow `Pete`'s guidelines. If you still need to expose the methods then do the following:

Add the methods to `ApplicationController` class and register the methods as helper methods by calling `helper_method`.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  helper_method :foo, :bar

private

  def foo
   "foo"
  end 

  def bar
   "bar"
  end 
end
```

Comment: Will the methods be available to any helper in the project if I add the methods as helper methods? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, if you add to `ApplicationController` it will.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could share some code between controllers:

1. Application controller: If the code in question is an action/method which ought to be in a controller, but could be used by several controllers (or all of them), then this might be a place to put it.
2. the 'lib' directory. just a general purpose place to put code which should be shared.
3. Put it in the model. This may or may not be applicable, but its worth taking a good look at the code you're trying to move and thinking about whether it is something which makes sense on a model (instead of a controller or random class/module in lib).

Comment: Thanks for the reply pete. For some reason putting code in the application controller seems dirty. I have a method related to a model but the same method should be callable by the controller and a method in the application helper.